# Django EmailMessgae() Error: MIMEPart.__init__()

Tags: python, django, email-validation

This is my views file:
[image: and this is the screenshot of the error]

I have made a token file to generate a link
and info file for details like `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and etc.

```
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        email_subject = "Confirm your email @XYZ"
        message2 = render_to_string('email_confirmation.html',{
            'name': myuser.first_name,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(myuser.pk)),
            'token': generate_token.make_token(myuser),
        })

        email = EmailMessage(
            email_subject,
            message2,
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            [myuser.email],
        )
        email.fail_silently=False
        email.send()
```

Comment: what is EmailMessage?

Comment: Email Message is an attribute of the email module and this is where the problem is ```email = EmailMessage()``` you don't have to know the whole code..

Answer (score 4):

Had this same issue as well, but, it turned out that I was importing the `EmailMessage` class.

Instead of doing this:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
```

Use:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`EmailMessage(...)`**[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-class) don't have any method named as `send_mail()` it has to be `send()` and **`EmailMessage`** don't have any attribute named as `fail_silently` it's a parameter passed to `send()` method so finally your code will look like this

```
email = EmailMessage(
            email_subject,
            message2,
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            [myuser.email],
        )
email.content_subtype = "html" # can specify type of your content
email.send(fail_silently=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, send_mail was a typo but your code didn't work too.. i got the exact same error cause the interpreter didn't run past ```email = EmailMessage()```

Comment: Did you removed `fail_silently` and added as argument to send function? and I think error is comming `MIMEPart` are you trying to send file or media in email ?

Comment: yes i did and i also removed ```email.content_subtype``` but didn't work